# Lifting a function which takes implicit parameter using functor (Scalaz7)

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

Just started learning Scalaz. Here is my code

```
trait Monoid[A] {
     def mappend(a1: A, a2: A): A
     def mzero: A
}

object Monoid {
    implicit val IntMonoid: Monoid[Int] = new Monoid[Int] {
        def mappend(a1: Int, a2: Int): Int = a1 + a2
        def mzero: Int = 0
    }

    implicit val StringMonoid: Monoid[String] = new Monoid[String] {
        def mappend(a1: String, a2: String): String = a1 + a2
        def mzero: String = ""
    }
}

trait MonoidOp[A] {
    val F: Monoid[A]
    val value: A
    def |+|(a2: A): A = F.mappend(value, a2)
}

object MonoidOp{
    implicit def toMonoidOp[A: Monoid](a: A): MonoidOp[A] = new MonoidOp[A]{
        val F = implicitly[Monoid[A]]
        val value = a
    }
}
```

I have defined a function (just for the sake of it)

```
def addXY[A: Monoid](x: A, y: A): A = x |+| y
```

I want to lift it so that it could be used using Containers like Option, List, etc. But when I do this

```
def addXYOptioned = Functor[Option].lift(addXY)
```

It says `error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type scalaz.Monoid[A]
       def addOptioned = Functor[Option].lift(addXY)`

How to lift such functions?

Comment: Two things: (1) Your function takes two arguments instead of one (strictly speaking it has two argument lists, since the context bound is an implicit parameter). (2) I don't think it is possible to use context bounds with functors, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849142/how-can-scalaz-functor-be-given-a-higher-kinded-type-with-a-context-bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `addXY` needs a `Monoid[A]` but there is no `Monoid[A]` in scope when used in `addXYOptioned`, so you also need to add the `Monoid` constraint to `addXYOptioned`.

The next problem is that [`Functor.lift`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.4/scalaz_2.11-7.2.4-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.Functor@lift[A,B](f:A=%3EB):F[A]=%3EF[B]) only lifts a function `A => B`, but we can use [`Apply.lift2`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.2.4/scalaz_2.11-7.2.4-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.Apply@lift2[A,B,C](f:(A,B)=%3EC):(F[A],F[B])=%3EF[C]) to lift a function `(A, B) => C`.

Using the `Monoid` from Scalaz itself :

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def addXY[A: Monoid](x: A, y: A): A = x |+| y

def addXYOptioned[A: Monoid] = Apply[Option].lift2(addXY[A] _)
```

We could generalize `addXYOptioned` to make it possible to lift `addXY` into any type constructor with an `Apply` instance :

```
def addXYApply[F[_]: Apply, A: Monoid] = Apply[F].lift2(addXY[A] _)

addXYApply[List, Int].apply(List(1,2), List(3,4))
// List[Int] = List(4, 5, 5, 6)

addXYApply[Option, Int].apply(1.some, 2.some)
// Option[Int] = Some(3)
```