# Lifting Functions using Cats Functor

Tags: scala, scala-cats

with Cats, I can write this simple program

```
def foo(x: Int) = x + 1
val bar = Functor[Future](foo)
```

and Now I can do a `bar(future(1))` and get a `Future.Success(2)` as a result. Very good.

But suppose my function was

```
def foo[T](x: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) : String = {...}
```

Now if I try to lift this function

```
def futureFoo = Functor[Future].lift(foo)
```

I get a compiler error `No Manifest available for T.`

So how do I lift this function?

I searched and found this thread (which is for scalaz)

[Lifting a function which takes implicit parameter using functor (Scalaz7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38300335/lifting-a-function-which-takes-implicit-parameter-using-functor-scalaz7)

But I still couldn't create anything which worked for me. I tried

```
val futureFoo = Functor[T].lift2(foo[T] _)
```

but this doesn't compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in Scala cannot have implicit parameters, so when you try to eta-expand a method with an implicit parameter into a function, the implicit needs to be resolved *before* the function itself is applied. That is, at the time of eta-expansion. The compiler doesn't have a generic `Manifest[T]` in scope, but `futureFoo` can require one.

```
def foo[T](x: T)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) : String = ""

scala> def optionFoo[T: Manifest] = Functor[Option].lift(foo[T] _)
optionFoo: [T](implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T])Option[T] => Option[String]
```

I used `Option` because I didn't have a `Functor[Future]` readily available, the the same concept applies. Note that in order to use this, you'll need to supply the type parameter manually for it to return the correct function.

```
scala> optionFoo[Int].apply(Option(1))
res2: Option[String] = Some()
```